# Monero cli transfer all funds from my wallet to a new address?

Tags: sweep-transaction, transfer

I know about the "sweep_all" option, but doesn't that just sweep all coins to your current wallet? What if I wanted to send ALL my monero to a new address? I was going to use transfer command but you'd have to specific exactly how much with fee accounted for. I don't know if sweep all can *SEND OUT* to another address.

Comment: Kind of duplicate of that ^ question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can just use the **sweep_all** option in replacement of transfer and it will send out ALL your coins to the new address.

Just do:

```
sweep_all < address >
```